# Subscribe to a component in Angular

Tags: angular, subscribe

I am trying to do something and I am not sure how to do that...

My folders are kind of like that:

```
[src
 | app
  | dashboard-folder
    | *other components* 
    | **dashboard** ----------------> my component, which I want to display now
      dashboard.component.html
      dashboard.component.ts
  | core
    | *other folders*
    | services
      sidebar.service.ts  
  | layout
    | header
    | **sidebar**
  **layout.component.html**
  layout.component.ts
  layout.module.ts]
```

My page, where I display everything, is the layout.component.html. Now I have in my screen: my header, my sidebar, and a very nice "dashboard-works!"

What I need to do is to display the sidebar only when I want to, because I don't need it in all my screens. So now I am working with my dashboard and, particularly, I don't need the sidebar. (In my mind, it sounds like "I need to unsuscribe the sidebar").

So, I am wondering if I could do some property in the sidebar.service, which I could subscribe from my dashboard.component.ts at the ngOnInit.

Something like this (sidebar.service.ts)

```
sidebar$ = new ReplaySubject<any>();
```

And something like this (dashboard.component)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sidebarService.sidebar$.next(SidebarComponent);} }
```

As you all can see I'm junior and I am very very lost now, so If you can help me someway, I would appreciate it so much!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can achieve what you're asking for (sidebar only on certain pages) just with routing. In your base route you add "sidebar" and "notSidebar" as routes, then add the components you want to display a sidebar on as child routes. This has the advantage that rather than destroying and remaking your sidebar component every time you go between two pages your sidebar component will remain loaded until you go to a non-sidebar route.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex!!! So if I understand, do that with a service is not the right way. Is that correct?

Comment: There's no right or wrong way but in my opinion this makes your app easier to organise. Say you want to add a login page to your app; you can just look in your routes and clearly see that it should be a child of "notSidebar".